# What the heck is this icon in the Atom Editor and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

It might have popped up when I was trying shortcuts out but even after trying a variety of the atom shortcuts I can't seem to get rid of it.

[image: Icon]

Comment: Was somebody painting your ceiling recently?

Comment: Oh wait, I *just* got that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Asked](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-stop-atom-from-displaying-a-touchscreen-insertion-point-when-run-in-a-vm-under-a-host-that-is-not-touch-enabled/19942) on the atom.io discussion board, turns out I just have to wait for atom to [update](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/7877) it's electron to  a version where this bug doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Window: Reload` command (shortcut: pressing `ctrl-alt-cmd-l`), it will try to reload the entire window and refresh everything.

Can you provide more details on what shortcut have you tried?